# Regular Expression pattern ValueError

Tags: python, regex

In the following code I am trying to match the digits, which can either be 16 or 15 digits  and may have spaces or `-` in between every 4 digits.

I get an error as

```
ValueError: Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import re

p_number = re.compile(r'(\d{15}|\d{16}|\d{4}[\s-]\d{4}[\s-]\d{4}[\s-]\d{4})')
c=["1234567891234567","123456789123456","1234 5678 9123 4567","1234-5678-9123-4567","1234567891111111tytyyyy"]

for a in c:
  #re.search(c,p_number,flag=0)
  matchObj = re.search( p_number , a, re.M|re.I)
  if matchObj:
     print "match found"
  else:
     print "No match!!"
```

Comment: This seems to be dependent on Python version! I just fixed this problem in code that used to work on my Debian server, in the Exim storage plugin of the pysieved program. The code was passing flags in the search calls. Luckily I was easily able to move the flags to where the regex is compiled (it wasn't using different flags in different places).

Comment: So you maybe didn't do anything "wrong"; you just copied some example for a different version of Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the flags to the `.compile()` call instead:

```
p_number = re.compile(r'(\d{15}|\d{16}|\d{4}[\s-]\d{4}[\s-]\d{4}[\s-]\d{4})', re.M|re.I)
```

and you can call `.search()` on the compiled pattern:

```
matchObj = p_number.search(a)
```

Your full script then becomes:

```
import re

p_number = re.compile(r'(\d{15}|\d{16}|\d{4}[\s-]\d{4}[\s-]\d{4}[\s-]\d{4})', re.M|re.I)
c=["1234567891234567","123456789123456","1234 5678 9123 4567","1234-5678-9123-4567","1234567891111111tytyyyy"]

for a in c:
    matchObj = p_number.search(a)
    if matchObj:
        print "match found"
    else:
        print "No match!!"
```

and prints `match found` 5 times.

Comment: @Rajeev: Then you didn't change the code correctly. I just tested your pattern, it works fine.

Comment: @Rajeev delete any `*.pyc` files in the directory and try it again.